# what is the name of the model for the describing strategy between R&D and Professional Services

Tags: organization, engineering

Is there a model that describes the different strategies that a company may use where the organisation is split into an engineering division and a professional services division?

This is the sort of model that is followed by companies like Microsoft, whereby Engineering (or R&D) produce the core software, and professional services can then help clients implement that software.

Comment: I've added this question here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62281/strategy/62284#62284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that there is a specific name for that "model", but it's a reasonably common approach.  In addition to Microsoft (your example), AT&T*, HP, IBM, and quite a few others follow the same approach.  Even Dell and others are starting to embrace this approach.

The reasons should be fairly obvious.

R&D activities need to be run in a different manner than a typical profit / loss model.  R&D is explicitly for activities that may never pan out.  The corporation may push the R&D towards more likely to be practical / applicable efforts, but there isn't a guarantee that a product will result.  As an example, IBM used to heavily fund basic research.  As of the mid-2000's, researchers were encouraged to focus on aspects that were more likely to be applicable to market needs.

Services divisions are a typical example of a normal profit / loss model.  A Services division can measure utilization rates, profit margins (or losses), service backlogs, etc...   All of which are in alignment with selling a product (a service).

---

<sub>*I'm not certain about AT&T having a separate R&D division anymore, but they certainly used to.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'm interested in the different approaches for the interaction between R&D and Professional Services.  For example, is it ok for R&D deliver unfinished software components that R&D finish?  When would this work?  When wouldn't it work?  I think I need to post this as a new question...

Comment: @user1502048 - yes, that would be a separate question.  Short answer to the new questions:  R&D frequently (<hyperbole> always!!! </hyperbole>) delivers not-quite-ready for production code, but that's the nature of their work.  Services folk are in the field making things production ready and aren't as good at finding new things.  R&D is finding new things but isn't so great at making production ready.

Comment: I think I have confused Engineering with R&D.  Using the example of Microsoft: Microsoft R&D should produce the conceptual product.  Microsoft Engineering should make production quality products.  Microsoft Professional Services should help clients implement the product?

Comment: @user1502048 - I'm not as familiar with MS's organization, but what you described sounds accurate, yes.